# Divs not floating properly

Tags: css, html, overflow, css-float

I have a parent div, and it houses a bunch of child divs. One of those is floated left, but the rest are floated right. It worked fine when only a few of the divs were floated right, but I've since added more and the results appear like this:

[image]

Light green is parent div background, other colors are the divs in question. A few actually float correctly for some reason, but green should be after the blue, and the pink after the red.

I have `overflow: hidden;` on the parent-most div, and the height has no affect on this child-div behavior.

How should I fix this?

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
#reviews {
background-color: #16ff21; //green
float: right;
text-align: left;
text-indent: 40px;
width: 40%;
height: 150px;
}
#rating {
background-color: #ff114b; //red
float: right;
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 200%;
height: 150px;
}
#validFor {
background-color: #19ceff; //blue
float: right;
width: 40%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 200%;
height: 150px;
}
#stats {
background-color: #ffe8e5; //pink
width: 40%;
float: right;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
font-size: 250%;
}
```

Here's the parent div of all that up there:

```
#description {
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
}
```

And the parent div of #description:

```
#main {
background-color: #d3ffd3;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 75%;
text-align: center;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add clear: right; for all but the first div that you want to be flush with the right border.  Otherwise, if there's width for them, multiple right-floated divs will hunch up next to each other on the same line.

Comment: Note: adding clear:both may have unintended consequences because of your single left-floated element.  If you use clear:both, then the div that rule is applied to will appear under BOTH the previous left and right-floated elements, which seems like it would be a problem if your left-floated div was of greater height...

Answer (score 1):

Have you added "clear:left or clear:both" to the ones floated right? I may not be understanding the question completely. Post your code somewhere and Ill take a look, could also be due to the XHTML structure. Also, not sure if it's in your real code but `//` is a js comment. /`*comment*/` is css

EDIT*******
just use a .clear {clear:both;} and apply it to each child div. works fine for me. Code below:

.clear{clear:both;}

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

```
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="validFor" class="clear"></div>

<div id="reviews" class="clear"></div>

<div id="rating" class="clear"></div>

<div id="stats" class="clear"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to `clear:both` so that the floats appear one under the other

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have trouble positioning your div with "float". You should note this case: assume you have 4 div which are:

```
[div 1][div 2][div 3][div 4]

[div 1]: float left
[div 2,3,4]: float right
```

The effects will show:

```
[div 1][div 4][div 3][div 2]
```

It's because the CSS style the element from left to right, and the div who is "lefter" takes priority. Hope this helps.